# save image from MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork to NSDocument

Tags: ios, cgimage, nsdocument

Currently I want to get the Album Artwork from music library (MPMedia) and save it as png or jpg file.

Here is my code:

```
UIImage *albumImage = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",documentsDirectory, titleWithID];
UIImage *image = albumImage; 
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```

But the process stop at  `NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`

I get the error:

> [MPConcreteMediaItemArtwork CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed33c80

Apparently the album artwork is `CGImage` I can't save it as png.
Any idea? please help.

Answer (score 4):

For a year old question:

```
[[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 320.0)];
```

To get a UIImage from a MPConcreteMediaItemArtwork you must use imageWithSize:, specifying the images dimensions.